# Start SSIS package in sql Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to configure mssql in ubuntu, and I am having a hard to start the SSIS package. According to this link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ssis

I need to run this command :
dtexec /F package name /DE protection password

but I don't know what to indicate in package name and protection password.

Help please :)

Answer (score 0):

The package name is defined inside the package as a property when it's created and many times is the same that package file name without extension.

The package password is also set during package creation, is used to cipher connections string passwords and other sensitive data.

In conclusion, you can see the package name if you open the package in Visual Studio, or any text editor. Package password must be provided by package creator.

Comment: Ok, I'll check that. Thank you!